# sklearn.preprocessing._data.MinMaxScaler is not a supported Transformer When the model is converted to PMML using sklearn2pmml

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pmml

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler,MinMaxScaler
from sklearn2pmml.pipeline import PMMLPipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper

mapper = DataFrameMapper([
        (model_col,[SimpleImputer(strategy = "most_frequent"),MinMaxScaler()])
    ])

clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=200,learning_rate=0.1,max_depth=5,random_state=10)
gbdt_pipeline = PMMLPipeline([('mapper', mapper), ("classifier", clf)])

sklearn2pmml(gbdt_pipeline,"gbdt.pmml",with_repr=True)
```

Convert to PMML to report an error. The error is as follows

```
Standard output is empty
Standard error:
 28, 2020 4:04:05  org.jpmml.sklearn.Main run
Ϣ: Parsing PKL..
 28, 2020 4:04:05  org.jpmml.sklearn.Main run
Ϣ: Parsed PKL in 80 ms.
 28, 2020 4:04:05  org.jpmml.sklearn.Main run
Ϣ: Converting..
 28, 2020 4:04:05  org.jpmml.sklearn.Main run
: Failed to convert
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value object (Python class sklearn.preprocessing._data.MinMaxScaler) is not a supported Transformer
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.CastFunction.apply(CastFunction.java:43)
    at com.google.common.collect.Lists$TransformingRandomAccessList$1.transform(Lists.java:612)
    at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:47)
    at sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper.initializeFeatures(DataFrameMapper.java:72)
    at sklearn.Initializer.encodeFeatures(Initializer.java:41)
    at sklearn.Transformer.updateAndEncodeFeatures(Transformer.java:85)
    at sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.encodeFeatures(Pipeline.java:83)
    at sklearn2pmml.pipeline.PMMLPipeline.encodePMML(PMMLPipeline.java:203)
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.Main.run(Main.java:145)
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.Main.main(Main.java:94)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDict to sklearn.Transformer
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)
    at org.jpmml.sklearn.CastFunction.apply(CastFunction.java:41)
    ... 9 more
```

The scikit-learn I used is 0.22.2, and when I use version 0.21, there are no errors
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Scikit-Learn renamed several modules between 0.21.X and 0.22.X development branches. For example, the `sklearn.preprocessing.data` module became `sklearn.preprocessing._data` (the leading underscore should be interpreted that this is a private module now).

You're using an outdated SkLearn2PMML package version which does not know about 0.22.X modules yet. Please update the SkLearn2PMML package to the latest (`pip install --upgrade sklearn2pmml`) and the problem will be resolved.